# Ozzie flow not able to hive-ql having UDF add command

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hiveql

I am creating oozie workflow where I am calling hive sqls sequentially.

First sql has simple transformation logic. While second has temporary function creation command and add lookup files commands. I am using this UDF further in sql.

ADD JAR ****;

CREATE  TEMPORARY FUNCTION XXXXX AS ...;

ADD FILE *****;

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4" name="hive-wf">
    <credentials>
        <credential name="hive_credentials" type="hcat">
            <property>
                <name>hcat.metastore.uri</name>
                <value>XXXXXXXX</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>hcat.metastore.principal</name>
                <value>XXXXXXXX</value>
            </property>
        </credential>
    </credentials>
    <start to="hive-1" />
    <action name="hive-1" cred="hive_credentials">
        <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>XXXXXXX</job-tracker>
            <name-node>XXXXXXX</name-node>
            <job-xml>/XXXXXX/oozie/oozie-hive-site.xml</job-xml>
            <configuration>
               <property>
                <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                <value>default</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <script>/XXXXXXX/hive_1.sql</script>
    </hive>
    <ok to="hive-2" />
    <error to="fail" />
</action>
<action name="hive-2" cred="hive_credentials">
    <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>XXXXXXXX</job-tracker>
        <name-node>XXXXXXXX</name-node>
        <job-xml>/XXXXXX/oozie/oozie-hive-site.xml</job-xml>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                <value>default</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <script>/XXXXXXX/hive_2.sql</script>
    </hive>
    <ok to="end" />
    <error to="fail" />
</action>
<kill name="fail">
    <message>Hive failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<end name="end" />
```

First hql script is executed successfully. Workflow is killed while executing second hql script giving below error.

**JOB[0000044-140317190624992-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[-] E1100: Command precondition does not hold before execution, [, coord action is null], Error Code: E1100**

It throws error while executing commands to ADD UDF.(ADD JAR,CREATE TEMPORARY,ADD FILE).

I searched on this error and I got some links to ignore the error !!!

But, my actual sql using hive UDF given in second Hql script is not executed.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

The `add jar` path is a local machine path.

Oozie actions are run on datanodes. There is a possibility it cannot find the jar on the datanode and hence gives an error (Check the mapreduce logs , you would find the reason)

If this is a issue, one workaround can be to put the file in HDFS and copy it to local filesytem on the datanode during execution